# Unsupported Media Type issue when including Apache Wink Client in my WAR

Tags: websphere, apache-wink, websphere-liberty

I'm hitting the following issue when doing a POSTing a JSON message to my REST service in WebSphere Liberty.

This **ONLY happens** when I bundle the Apache Wink Client jars inside my WAR.

```
[29/01/14 18:52:57:634 GMT] 00000027 org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             I The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (415 - Unsupported Media Type) with message 'null' while processing POST request sent to http://host:9080/my-war/myrest/req
```

The dependencies I'm adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
    <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
    <artifactId>wink-client-apache-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Liberty version:

```
WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1 (wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639)
```

Is there a way to work around this issue?

## Fixed

Following Anton's link below I changed my `wink-client` dependency scope to `<scope>provided</scope>` and added the following to the WAS Liberty `server.xml`:

```
<application location="C:\myproject\target\myapp.war" type="war">
    <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec,ibm-api,api,third-party"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found related post on developer works portal.
It might help.

[Developerworks forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=6111535e-4cde-4849-8ab0-8206928c1bc7)